# Unexpected token error when outputting HTML

Tags: javascript

I tried to output all plugins to browser.

But I received ac `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` exception after this line:

`document.write(<tr><td>);`

I am missing something, but what?

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of Plug-Ins</title>
    </head> 
        <body>
            <h1>List of Plug-Ins</h1>
            <hr>
            The following is a list of the plug-ins installed in this
                copy of Netscape, generated using the JavaScript
                navigator.plugins object:
            <hr>                
                <table border>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Plug-in Name</th>
                        <th>Filename</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <script>
                        for(i=0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
                            document.write(<tr><td>);
                            document.write(navigator.plugins[i].name);
                            document.write(</td><td>);
                            document.write(navigator.plugins[i].filename);
                            document.write(</td><td>);
                            document.write(navigator.plugins[i].description);
                            document.write(</td></td>);
                        }
                    </script>
                </table>
        </body>    
</html>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML tags need to be inside `""`.

Change your script to the following:

```
for(i=0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].name);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].filename);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(navigator.plugins[i].description);
    document.write("</td></td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('</td></td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put quotations in the writes, if you want to write something as HTML in Javascript.